# How to proceed this definite integral?

Tags: definite-integrals

$\int_{\frac{1}{2014}}^{2014}\frac{\arctan x}{x}\text{d}x$

Comment: integrating from $\frac1{2014}$ to $2014$?

Comment: And what did you try? Why can't you do it? Where do you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint: $\arctan(x) + \arctan(1/x) = \pi/2$ for $x > 0$. Try adding the integral to itself (perhaps with some changes to it by substitution).

Comment: No, we can't assume arctan(x) is constant - only that arctan(x) + arctan(1/x) is. But, notice that $\int_{1/2014}^{2014} \arctan(x) dx + \int_{1/2014}^{2014} \arctan(1/x) dx = \int_{1/2014}^{2014} \arctan(x) + \arctan(1/x) dx$

Comment: Are you trying to re-format the question?